# Which MongoDB Aggregate Pipeline is better - [$match, $project, $group] or [$project, $match, $group]

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to perform a `$group` operation on a set of matched documents. So I'm using a `$match` first and then a `$group`. But where should I place a `$project`? Should it be before `$match` or after `$match`?

`$match` reduces the number of documents (mostly) that is transferred to the next operation in the pipeline. But `$project` reduces the amount of data that is cascaded to the next operation in the pipeline, though does not reduce the number of documents.

So which sequence should I prefer?

**Sample Data :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61325594fac485c58bb97fd3"),
    "date" : NumberLong(1465776000000),
    "account_id" : 794876.0,
    "amount" : 8797.0,
    "transaction_code" : "buy",
    "symbol" : "nvda",
    "price" : "46.53873172406391489630550495348870754241943359375",
    "total" : "409401.2229765902593427995271"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61325594fac485c58bb97fd2"),
    "date" : NumberLong(1325030400000),
    "account_id" : 794875.0,
    "amount" : 1197.0,
    "transaction_code" : "buy",
    "symbol" : "nvda",
    "price" : "12.7330024299341033611199236474931240081787109375",
    "total" : "15241.40390863112172326054861"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61325594fac485c58bb97fd6"),
    "date" : NumberLong(1022112000000),
    "account_id" : 794876.0,
    "amount" : 4521.0,
    "transaction_code" : "buy",
    "symbol" : "nvda",
    "price" : "10.763069758141103449133879621513187885284423828125",
    "total" : "48659.83837655592869353426977"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61325594fac485c58bb97fd5"),
    "date" : NumberLong(1101081600000),
    "account_id" : 794875.0,
    "amount" : 253.0,
    "transaction_code" : "buy",
    "symbol" : "amzn",
    "price" : "37.77441226157566944721111212857067584991455078125",
    "total" : "9556.926302178644370144411369"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61325594fac485c58bb97fd4"),
    "date" : NumberLong(1472601600000),
    "account_id" : 794875.0,
    "amount" : 6146.0,
    "transaction_code" : "sell",
    "symbol" : "ebay",
    "price" : "32.11600884852845894101847079582512378692626953125",
    "total" : "197384.9903830559086514995215"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61325594fac485c58bb97fd7"),
    "date" : NumberLong(936144000000),
    "account_id" : 794875.0,
    "amount" : 955.0,
    "transaction_code" : "buy",
    "symbol" : "csco",
    "price" : "27.992136535152877030441231909207999706268310546875",
    "total" : "26732.49039107099756407137647"
}
```

Which of the following query is better? Or, is there any tangible difference between the following two?

```
db.getCollection('temp123').aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      account_id: 1,
      transaction_code: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      transaction_code: "buy"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$account_id",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

or

```
db.getCollection('temp123').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      transaction_code: "buy"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      account_id: 1,
      transaction_code: 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$account_id",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Note:**
This is not the actual data and is just added for reference. In the actual data, the average document size ranges between 1 to 5 MB and the number of documents ranges between 0.1 to 10 Million.

Comment: You need to post the sample data and expected output and tried code. We are not god :D to predict your mind

Comment: Hope the added data is sufficient.

Comment: i think try both of them and log the time diff of start to end and compare which is better

Comment: there is no need to project, MongoDB optimizer will do it anyways if you dont need the fields(dont add project stages unless a reason), use only the `$match` stage and make index on the field if you can, i think you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Even you setup your pipeline with `$project` + `$match` + `$group`, MongoDB's query optimer will shift your `$match` step into the first place. 
Run `db.getCollection('temp123').explain().aggregate([...])` for the verification

> Aggregation pipeline operations have an optimization phase which
> **attempts to reshape the pipeline for improved performance**.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

**Note:** It is redundant to use `$project` stage, since the `$group` stage takes only a single field.

**BTW:** You may get `Aggregation Pipeline Optimization`:

1. Create compound index `{"transaction_code": 1, "account_id": 1}`
2. Apply `$match` + `$sort` + `$group` sequence

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#std-label-group-pipeline-optimization